# How to resize lightslider container

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, what a great slider! Thank you for sharing with us who struggle with coding. I am embarrassed to ask this, but after reading 189 stackoverflow posts and many web searches, I am at a dead end. I have tried everything I know in the .js and .css but have not had any luck.

I need to make the entire slider package larger. I have two columns on my page and I need to resize the slider to fill the larger right column container. I know this will effect the thumbnails but I understand the option for resizing the thumbnails perfectly.

I really feel that I am overthinking it an am missing something obvious. I am using lightslider 1.1.3 downloaded from github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider. No changes to the code other than the options. Installed and runs beautifully. The jsfiddle at http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/ is pretty much exactly what I am running with no issues other than the sizing thing. I'm not a coder but I have some basic understanding and experience. Thanks for any help!

Comment: why don't you try `autoWidth: true` option?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I changed the var default of autoWidth to true already and it has no effect. I switched browsers and cleared cache just to be sure nothing was hanging. I am using an image that is larger than the slider is now and it simply crops the image. Searching for autoWidth only pulls up results in IF statements.

Comment: Sorry. Let it rest for a while then the answer was obvious. The size is forced in the HTML. I tried to delete this question, but apparently I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Play with the values of the width and the height.

```html
<ul id="lightSlider">
    <li data-thumb="img1.jpg">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img1.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can play with the values of height and size to acquire the required dimensions